# Conditionally fill new added column using r

Tags: r

I have a df looks like below.

```
> a <- data.frame(col1=c(1, 2),col2=c(10,11))
> a
  col1 col2
1    1   10
2    2   11
```

Then I want to fill two extra columns conditionally, `col3 and col4`.

if `col1 == 1`, then copy `col2` to `col3`, and fill 0 in `col4`.

if `col1 == 2`, then copy `col2` to `col4`, and fill 0 in `col3`.

Finally I can see a df.

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4
1    1   10   10    0  
2    2   11    0   11
```

Any good packages or basic R function can do this?

Comment: What have you tried? Is your actual problem more complex than this? for example more possible values for `col1`? and more than two columns that will be created?

Comment: Otherwise two simple `ifelse` work. `df$col3<-ifelse(df$col1==1, df$col2, 0)` and `df$col4<-ifelse(df$col1==2, df$col2, 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A case for `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

a <- data.frame(col1=c(1, 2),col2=c(10,11))

a %>% 
  mutate(col3=case_when(col1==1 ~ col2,
                        col1==2 ~ 0),
         col4=case_when(col1==2 ~ col2,
                        col1==1 ~ 0))
>  col1 col2 col3 col4
>1    1   10   10    0
>2    2   11    0   11
```

This will fill up col3 and col4 with `NA`'s if col1 is neither 1 or 2. An ifelse statement such as the one from Anatolii is also possible, but in my opinion it should not be that general.

```
library(dplyr)

a <- data.frame(col1=c(1, 2),col2=c(10,11))

a %>% 
  mutate(col3=ifelse(col1==1, col2,
                     ifelse(col1==2, 0, NA)),
         col4=ifelse(col1==1, 0, 
                     ifelse(col1==2, col2, NA)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do with an `ifelse` statement:

```
library(dplyr)

a <- data.frame(col1=c(1, 2),col2=c(10,11))

a %>% 
  mutate(col3 = ifelse(col1 == 1, col2, 0),
         col4 = ifelse(col1 == 2, col2, 0))

>  col1 col2 col3 col4
1    1   10   10    0
2    2   11    0   11
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be overcomplicating it by looking for a package or an if-else.... A simple index should do it.

```
col1 <- c(1,2)
col2 <- c(10,11)
a <- data.frame(col1,col2,col3 = 0, col4 = 0)

a$col3[which(col1 == 1)] <- col2[which(col1 == 1)]
a$col4[which(col1 == 2)] <- col2[which(col1 == 2)]
```

results in

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4
1    1   10   10    0
2    2   11    0   11
```

The `which(col1 == 1)` statement declares that for each row of `col1` that equals `1`, you are copying that row into `col3`; the same thing with `col4` using `which(col1 == 2)`.